# ¿Cómo implementar cursor en consulta SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Tengo una query en Sql Server , esta me devuelve cuatro columnas :

***'Fecha' ,  ' IdFamiliaArticulo' ,  'NombreFamiliaArticulo',   'SumImporteId'***

Algo asi:

```
Fecha           IdFamiliaArticulo        NombreFamiliaArticulo       SumImporteId
21/12/2020        Zapato                     Zapato                      100.00
24/12/2020        Zapato                     Zapato                       300.20
28/12/2020        Camisa                     Camisa                      400.40
```

Entonces nesecito iterar (USANDO UN CURSOR) dentro de los registros devueltos para obtener una salida como la siguiente , sabiendo que el dia 1 corresponde al 01/12/2020

Algo asi:

```
 Dia        Zapato   Pantalon Camisas      SumImporte
  1         100        200      300          600
  2          3          5        2            10
  3          4          1        3             8
```

La query que estoy usando es la siguiente y es a la que nesecito implementar el cursor

```
SELECT  c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia, SUM(l.ImporteTotal) AS SumImporteId FROM CRMv2_000695..A_DocumentoLineaFactura l
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_DocumentoCabecera c ON c.IdCabecera = l.IdCabecera
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_Articulo a ON a.IdArticulo = l.IdArticulo
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_ArticuloFamilia af ON a.IdFamiliaArticulo = af.IdFamiliaArticulo
GROUP BY c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, no uses cursores porque bloquean la tabla entera. Es mejor utilizar un bucle while que ademas es más rápido:

```
Declare @IdFamiliaArticulo int
SELECT  c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia, SUM(l.ImporteTotal) AS SumImporteId, 0 as Procesado
into #procesar
FROM CRMv2_000695..A_DocumentoLineaFactura l
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_DocumentoCabecera c ON c.IdCabecera = l.IdCabecera
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_Articulo a ON a.IdArticulo = l.IdArticulo
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_ArticuloFamilia af ON a.IdFamiliaArticulo = af.IdFamiliaArticulo
GROUP BY c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia

While exists (select 1 from #procesar) Begin
 Select @IdFamiliaArticulo = IdFamiliaArticulo from #procesar where Procesado = 0 Order by ...

 //Aquí lo que quieras hacer dentro del bucle

Update #procesar set Procesado = 1 Where IdFamiliaArticulo = @IdFamiliaArticulo
End
```

Si aún quieres usar cursores (porque es una práctica para el profe), la sintaxis la tienes aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Aunque lo que pones ahí tiene toda la pinta de ser una pivot table: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

No soy muy bueno en esto pero creo que sería algo así. El problema son los nombres de las familias que no sé como hacer que los pille de la consulta.

```
SELECT Fecha, [250] AS Zapato, [251] AS Pantalon, [252] AS Camisa
FROM   
(SELECT  c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia, l.ImporteTotal FROM CRMv2_000695..A_DocumentoLineaFactura l
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_DocumentoCabecera c ON c.IdCabecera = l.IdCabecera
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_Articulo a ON a.IdArticulo = l.IdArticulo
    JOIN CRMv2_000695..A_ArticuloFamilia af ON a.IdFamiliaArticulo = af.IdFamiliaArticulo
) p  
PIVOT  
(  
Sum(ImporteTotal)
FOR IdFamiliaArticulo IN  
( [250], [251], [256], [257], [260] )  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.Fecha;
```

Comment: Hola @bsebe  en realidad es algo cualquier metodo para que me devuelva eso que nesecito seria buenisimo  si deseas mostrarme el ejemplo de  pivot table...Seria genial

Comment: ufff a ver si soy capaz. He editado mi respuesta pero no sé si funcionará. No suelo hacer pivots y no tengo práctica.

Comment: Gracias si salen las columnas ...La fecha bien ...pero las demas los valores en null

Comment: ¿has cambiado los valores 250,251, etc. por los ids de tus categorias? Lo siento, pero creo que mucho más no puedo ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

segui el siguiente tutorial:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

```
Mi Codigo:

 DROP TABLE #RegistrosParaCalculo
    END
    DECLARE @Fecha DATETIME ,@IdFamiliaArticulo VARCHAR(20),@NombreFamilia VARCHAR (70),@SumImporte MONEY;
    SELECT  c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia, SUM(l.ImporteTotal) AS SumImporte
        INTO #RegistrosParaCalculo
            FROM A_DocumentoLineaFactura l
                JOIN A_DocumentoCabecera c ON c.IdCabecera = l.IdCabecera
                JOIN A_Articulo a ON a.IdArticulo = l.IdArticulo
                JOIN A_ArticuloFamilia af ON a.IdFamiliaArticulo = af.IdFamiliaArticulo
            GROUP BY c.Fecha, a.IdFamiliaArticulo, af.NombreFamilia
    --PIVOTE 
    DECLARE @SqlPivot NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @NombreColumna1 NVARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE @NombreColumna2 NVARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE @ColumnaTotal NVARCHAR(1000);
    
    SELECT @NombreColumna1 = ISNULL(@NombreColumna1 + ',' , '') 
           + 'CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(NombreFamilia) + ',0))) as IMPORTE_' + NombreFamilia
    FROM (SELECT NombreFamilia FROM #RegistrosParaCalculo GROUP BY  NombreFamilia ) AS Familia
    SELECT @NombreColumna2 = ISNULL(@NombreColumna2 + ',' , '') 
           + QUOTENAME(NombreFamilia)
    FROM (SELECT NombreFamilia FROM #RegistrosParaCalculo GROUP BY  NombreFamilia ) AS Familia
    SELECT @ColumnaTotal = ISNULL(@ColumnaTotal + ' +' , '') 
           + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(NombreFamilia) + ',0) ' 
    FROM (SELECT NombreFamilia FROM #RegistrosParaCalculo GROUP BY  NombreFamilia ) AS Familia
    SET @SqlPivot =  N'SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,Fecha, 103) As FECHA , ' + @NombreColumna1 + 
                    ', CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(' + @ColumnaTotal + ')) AS IMPORTE_TOTAL ' +
                    ' FROM #RegistrosParaCalculo PIVOT (SUM(SumImporte) FOR NombreFamilia IN (' + @NombreColumna2 + ')) AS TablaInforme ' +
                    'GROUP BY(Fecha) HAVING CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(' + @ColumnaTotal + ')) > 0 '
    --print @SqlPivot;
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlPivot
```